# Getting (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests') error even though I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling

Tags: python, cmd

The error I am getting

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kieran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\StockRank.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I am using python 3.8

I tried:

```
 pip3 uninstall requests
```

and reinstalling, but I get

```
 Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\kieran\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\kieran\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests) (1.25.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\kieran\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\kieran\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests) (2.10)
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests-2.24.0
```

Once I try to run the program I get the same error message. I believe I am using the updated version of pip as well. Maybe It could be an issue with the paths, but I am not sure how to check that

Comment: Please provide more information. Maybe your app is using different version of Python besides what pip is using. More info will get you a solution.

Comment: Okay I have edited to include more information, maybe that helps?

Comment: 99% of this time this issue is caused by having multiple Python installs.  Are you using some kind of IDE that has it's own python install?

Comment: I am using idle which is running 3.8.5 is there anyway I can check if I am running multiple versions of Python @Kingsley

Comment: You can try `pip3 -V` and for the sake of completeness: `python -V` and `python3 -V`.

Comment: Also, `where python` and `where pip3` may be helpful

Comment: `C:\Users\Kieran>where python
C:\Users\Kieran\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

C:\Users\Kieran>where pip3
C:\Users\Kieran\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pip3.exe

C:\Users\Kieran>pip3 -V
pip 20.2.2 from C:\Users\Kieran\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)` does any of this look right or wrong. Im not sure if they are supposed to be in the AppData folder